# Neo4j Docker Config file

Tags: neo4j

Running Neo4j 3.1 community edition in docker container on:
Virtual Box host : Windows 10 Professional
Virtual Box Guest : RHEL 7.2 -3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP 
EST 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Docker version 1.13.0, build 49bf474

Run with conf directory inside docker image, ie

```
export NEO4J_DATA=/home/dpdev/dockerConfigs/Neo4j/data
export NEO4J_LOGS=/home/dpdev/dockerConfigs/Neo4j/logs
export NEO4J_CONF=/home/dpdev/dockerConfigs/Neo4j/conf
export NEO4J_NAME=DPDev-neo4j
docker run \
    --name=dpdev-Neo4j \
    --publish=7474:7474 \
    --publish=7687:7687 \
    --volume=$NEO4J_DATA:/data \
    --volume=$NEO4J_LOGS:/logs \
    neo4j:3.1
```

all works fine and I can access the admin on http://localhost:7474
inside the RHEL guest (docker host)
but

```
docker run \
    --name=dpdev-Neo4j \
    --publish=7474:7474 \
    --publish=7687:7687 \
    --volume=$NEO4J_DATA:/data \
    --volume=$NEO4J_LOGS:/logs \
    --volume=$NEO4J_CONF:/conf \
    neo4j:3.1
```

I cannot access the admin console as before on http://localhost:7474, when the conf file is on the docker host, rather than inside the docker image

NOTE: I am using the config file from the Neo4j dump command (no changes at all)

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to try using [host.docker.internal](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host) instead of localhost, perhaps it routes differently in each scenario.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).